# How do I solve a partial derivative $f(x,y)$ where $g(r,\theta)=f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates, chain-rule

We are given the following information:

1. $f(x,y)$ is differentiable.
2. $g(r, \theta) = f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$
3. $f_x(1,1)=-2$ and $f_y(1,1)=3$.

We are told to use the chain rule to find $g_r (\sqrt{2},\pi / 4)$.

Attempt 1:  (INCORRECT)

My first attempt to solve this involved me thinking about the vector created by the points $(1,1,-2)$ and $(1,1,3)$, which is just a straight line. I figure this implies that $x$ and $y$ are constants.

The next step I took was to integrate $f_x$ and $f_y$. Since $f_x(1,1)=-2 \implies f=-2x+c_y$ and $f_y(1,1)=3 \implies 3y+c_x$. Because the partial derivatives are from the same equation, we can say that $f(x,y)=-2x+3y$. Because $f_r=f_x \cos \theta + f_y \sin \theta$, and the partial derivatives are constants, $g_r (\sqrt{2},\pi / 4) = (-2) \cos \dfrac{\pi}{4} + 3 \sin \dfrac{\pi}{4} = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Comment: I suppose we have $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: The question doesn't say anything to the contrary, so I'd assume so.

Comment: Are $f_x$ and $f_y$ constant functions?

Comment: No, this is not right. From the partial derivatives *at a single point*, you can't say what the function $f(x,y)$ is for all $x$ and $y$. You were told to use the chain rule, weren't you, so why don't you try that instead?

Comment: I see the error in my reasoning. It could have been any linear (or higher order) combination of variables which add up to 1, like: $\{x^3-x^2+x: x=1\}$

Comment: Based on my notes, I have two equations which I think make sense here:

$f_r=f_x \cos \theta + f_y \sin \theta$ and $ f_\theta = f_y r \cos \theta - f_x r \sin \theta$.

I don't know if $f_x$ or $f_y$ are constant, but I do know they are differentiable which brings credibility to the fact that $f_x(1,1)=-2$ and $f_y(1,1)=3$. It doesn't matter if they are constant, the question is not asking about the partial derivatives.

I think I lack a contextual example for where this applies. Can I get an example of a question in physics or elsewhere?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to clarify that question: what kind of object should I get at the end of the calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second attempt at question, following guidance from the community.

Were given that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-2$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 3$

$f_r=f_x \cos \theta + f_y \sin \theta \\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}=(-2)\left( \cos \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) + (3) \left( \sin \dfrac{\pi}{4}\right) = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

I'll set $\theta=\phi$ for typographical convenience. Now, we have that $g_r=f_r.$ Also, setting $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi,$ we have that $$g_r=f_r=f_xx_r+f_yy_r.$$

Also note that when $r=\sqrt 2,\,\phi=π/4,$ we have that $(x,y)=(1,1).$

Can you now complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is basically correct, but there's a term missing from the left side of your second equation.  This should be
$$
\frac{\partial f}{
\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{
\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{
\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{
\partial r}\ .
$$

Comment: Thanks. I made the change and added it to my answer.